# jquery formdata returns null in express req.files

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, express

I am using Bootstrap/jquery for client side. On server side I am using node.js and express
The form is as follows:

```
<form id="signupform" action="">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <p>Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Contact" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="cover">Profile Picture</label>
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="cover">
                
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="sign-up">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My jquery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sign-up").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("username",$("#username").val())
        formData.append("email",$("#email").val())
        formData.append("contact",$("#contact").val())
        formData.append("password",$("#password").val())
        formData.append("cover",$("#cover")[0].files)
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/users/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

On server side, when I view the incoming request I see this:

```
 body: {
    username: 'Sree',
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    contact: '1',
    password: '1',
    cover: '[object FileList]'
  },
```

On the server side I am using express-fileupload, but the image is being sent in the body instead of req.files. How to send formData's file to req.files instead of body?

Comment: checkout this link - https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/. You have to use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form and check jquery code in given link.

Comment: What is the expectation about `[4]` in `formData.append("cover",$("#signupform")[4])`? I would suggest `formData.append("cover",$("#cover")[0].files)` where `[0]` is to get the DOM element inside the jQuery object and `.files` is the [fileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

Comment: You could do this `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('signupform'));` instead of getting each input manually. Remove the ids from the inputs and use `name` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing a File object to `append()`, to access the file object use the prop method to get access to the FileList and take the item at the first index

```
formData.append("cover", $("#cover").prop('files')[0])
```

Comment: I think the element should be $('#cover") but it works